# Laravel - Please advise on table name

Tags: laravel

I am in trouble with the name of the pivot table.

`products` ... Product master table
`shop` ... Shop master table.
`shop_sales` ... A table that links products and dates. It leads to another table. The column is `date` and `shop_id`.

I want to add a table to shop_sales to manage products and the number sold.

`shop_sale_products` vs `product_shop_sale`

Does laravel recommend `product_shop_sale`?

thanks.

Comment: what about `product_sales`?

Comment: Not sure what you're exactly trying to accomplish. Could you give a bit more details about your table structure and logic behind it